# Windows Machine Learning API: MCVE command line example without VS

Tags: windows, machine-learning, c++-winrt, windows-machine-learning

With [C++/WinRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/WinRT) Microsoft apparently made quite the effort to make their APIs standard-conformant.
And finally they've also released a [machine learning API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/integrate-model) along with a [code sample repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/tree/master).

Unfortunately, all samples are dependent on Visual Studio. Even the simplest command line demo ([CustomTensorization](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/tree/master/Samples/CustomTensorization)) requires `.snl` files and VisualStudio.

Is it possible to write code for this API without VisualStudio by just downloading an SDK and using a regular `make` file?

If so, how? Please post or point to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the machine learning API, but C++/WinRT is a header-only library that you can include and build from a developer command prompt quite easily. Here's a simple example:

```
C:\ml>type sample.cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")
#include <winrt/Windows.AI.MachineLearning.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::AI::MachineLearning;

int main()
{
    init_apartment();
    puts("Sample");
}

C:\ml>cl /EHsc /std:c++17 /nologo sample.cpp
sample.cpp

C:\ml>sample.exe
Sample
```

For an actual example using the machine learning API I'd suggest you start here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/get-started-desktop

But again, you can follow along and substitute Visual Studio with the command line and use cmake, or any other build system, if so desired.